# Upper bound on number of sets in a sub cover?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, compactness

An exercise in Strichartz asks "For which compact sets can you set an upper bound on the number of sets in a sub cover on an open cover?"

This doesn't make sense to me. How could there ever be an upper bound? If we are allowed to take any open cover that we want, then why not choose the open cover $\{ (-n,n): n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. This covers the whole line so it covers any compact subset. But $\{(-2n,2n)\}$ is a proper sub cover that has infinitely many elements. So what does Strichartz mean?

It seems to me that this question would make more sense if it were asking for an upper bound on the sizes of *minimal* sub covers.

Comment: Hint: is the statement true for finite sets?  What about countable sets (what if you change the topology?)

Comment: It seems to me to be false for all subsets, including finite ones, of the real line with the usual topology and this is what the author exclusively refers to.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a one point set is contained in at least one open set in any of its open covers.  So an upper bound of $1$ can be imposed for cardinalities of subcovers of covers of one point sets: "Every open cover of a one point set contains a subcover containing at most one open set."

> Consider $X = [1,n] \subset \Bbb{Z} \subset \Bbb{R}$ using the usual topology on $\Bbb{R}$.  Label each set with the elements of $X$ that it covers.  Any open cover contains at least one open set whose label contains "$1$", at least one open set whose label contains "$2$", ..., and at least one open set whose label contains "$n$".  The collection of these "at least one open set"s is a subcover, covering X, containing at most $n$ open sets.
> (It may contain fewer if an open set covering more than one point is chosen for more than one element of its label.  A subcover is not a multiset.)
>  The same argument works for any finite set if we use cardinality to find a bijection between elements of $X$ and the labels "$1$", "$2$", ..., "$n$".  Hence every open cover of a set of cardinality $n$ has a subcover containing at most $n$ open sets.

Comment: But you can always have redundant open sets in the sub cover. So this is not an upper bound on the number of sets in a sub cover. This is an upper bound on the number of sets in a *minimal* sub cover, right?

Comment: No.  A subcover is a set, not a multiset.  It *cannot* contains a repeated open set.

Comment: This is not what I mean by redundant open sets in the sub cover. I do not mean that you have repeats, only that you could have a proper sub cover $C'$ of a cover $C$ such that $C'$ itself has a proper sub cover $C''$ In other words, $K$ being the compact set, $K\subset \bigcup C''\subset \bigcup C' \subset \bigcup C$

Comment: You asked what Strichart means.  I've told you.  Twice.

Comment: In the statement  "Every open cover of a one point set contains a subcover containing at *most one* open set." what is the meaning of "at most"? Do you mean that Given any open cover of a one point set there are no open sub covers that have cardinalities greater than 1? This just seems false.

Comment: The phrase means exactly what it says.  Every cover contains a one element subcover.  It contains other subcovers, including the whole cover, but who cares?  It need only contain one small subcover to satisfy the bound.  I suspect you have two quantifiers swapped in whatever it is you imagine is being said.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48825/discussion-between-user140776-and-eric-towers).

Comment: So this works only for finite sets?

Comment: @erfgerwge : In the indiscrete topology, this is very easy.  However, I suspect OP meant "The Way of Analysis" (but did not say so), so we should expect the standard topology on $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{R}^n$.  Then there's no way to prevent an open cover of an infinite set requiring infinite subcovers (but we can reduce that to countably infinite -- see [Lindelöf space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_space) -- because $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{R}^n$ have countable bases: any open cover of $\Bbb{Q}$ and $\Bbb{Q}^n$, respectively, applying the "pick one per point" argument from the Answer.).

Answer (score 0):

So, given the compact set $X$, and an open cover $\mathcal A$ of it, here is a finite subcover.  What is the minimal size of such a finite subcover of $X$ chosen from $\mathcal A$?  Of course, that minimal size depends on which cover $\mathcal A$ you start with.  Strichartz is asking: could you have a compact set $X$ so that there is a number $N$ such that, for *any* open cover, there is a subcover of size at most $N$?

Comment: I think the answer is "no". Even if the compact set is *empty*, we can cover it in such a way that there are sub covers of size $n$ for each natural number $n$.

Comment: Take the MINIMUM of all sizes of subcovers.  For example, if the set has $12$ elements, the no matter how you cover it, there is a subcover with at most $12$ sets.  Are there infinite sets that also have this amazing property?

Comment: If a finite set has cardinality $n$, then $n$ is the upper bound. Do you have any hints for infinite sets?